# Regex to match two EXACT values and no leading or following characters

Tags: regex

First time post! I am not great with Regex but I am using a tag management system (TMS) that allows me to input some regex that has come in handy for a while until now because the URLs I wanted to match were pretty specific. I am using the Regex field in the TMS to exclusively match the two **BOLDED** areas of the URLs listed below:

- https://www.example.com**/folder/**
- https://www.example.com**/folder/index.html**

This is what I was using until I realized it matches EVERYTHING that contains "/folder/".

- /folder/|/folder/index.html

I do NOT want it to match anything after "/folder/", just the two listed URLs above.

Does anyone know what I need to use? The Regex field in the TMS seems a little limited and may not allow me to enter in some crazy looking stuff but I am willing to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not seem to know what dialect of regex you are dealing with, here is a speculative answer, which forces the regex to match *only if it is a suffix*. The `$` character stands for end of line.

```
/folder/$|/folder/index\.html$
```

Comment: So far it works like it should!  Thank you!!!  I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @user3842539, Please accept this answer if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a $ at the end.

i.e. so

```
/folder/$|/folder/index.html$
```

$ means matching the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want to do is match an exact URL, but optionally allow a specific suffix?

Try something like this:

`https://www\.example\.com/folder/(index.html)?$`

The `$` matches the end of the line. The `?` makes the previous group optional, which means this will match https://www.example.com/folder/ or https://www.example.com/folder/index.html but nothing else.